# Get selected controls from Pivot.ItemTemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a XAML:

```
<phone:Pivot  Name="pivot" SelectionChanged="pivot_SelectionChanged">            
              <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                        
                            <ViewportControl Name="viewport">
                            <Canvas Name="canvas">
                                <Image Name="image"  
                                        RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" 
                                        CacheMode="BitmapCache"

                                        Source="{Binding ImageSource}">
                                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="xform"/>
                                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                                </Image>
                            </Canvas>
                        </ViewportControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot>
```

Can I get current  ViewportControl, Canvas, etc for selected item? For example

```
private void pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //get ViewportControl, Canvas, etc           
        }
```

Not necessarily with `SelectionChanged`, may have other solutions?

Comment: very useful article on my question http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you have to search for them. You need to use `VisualTreeHelper` and hunt for children of the desired type.

Or you can have some mapping in the code-behind for all controls and the parent pivot items.